# Sorting a list by median

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors coming from a list of dataframes, and i want to boxplot them:

```
list1 <- lapply(dir(), read.table,  sep = "\t", dec = ".")
names(list1) <- gsub(".tsv", "", c(dir()))
vector1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) {as.vector(unlist(x))})
boxplot(vector1)
```

I want to either sort the list or the boxplot by the median of its element. I have found solutions with reorder, but i have troubles with applying it here, as i am lacking factor levels in my dataset (i cannot pass an atomic vector to reorder, i think).

Thank you again!

Comment: Is there a reason not to put this in a dataframe?  Also, if you can provide more information or, better yet, a small example of your data structure, that would be helpful.

Comment: boxplot(vector1) worked easier than boxplotting the unlisted dataframes. Also, i am using melt from reshape to work with ggplot2. melting vector1 gives a less complex structure than melting list1. Ill give some example data asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
set.seed(1)

## unordered
list1 <- lapply(c(1,4,2,3), function(i)rnorm(100,mean=i))
vector1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) {as.vector(unlist(x))})
boxplot(vector1)

## ordered
med <- sapply(list1, median)
boxplot(vector1[order(med, decreasing=TRUE)])
```

Comment: This worked fine, except that i had to do med <- sapply(vector1, median), as for the list i received: Error in median.default(X[[1L]], ...) : need numeric data